# Place note page on the left of slide

Tags: beamer, pgfpages

How can I make the note page using `pgfpages` appear on the left of the slide? (I want to do this to have the green screen slide on the left for online videos using OBS). This MWE produces the notes on the right be default.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{color}
\pagecolor{green}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

\setbeamertemplate{note page}{\insertnote}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

A frame.
\note{}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

gives:

[image: Output with notes on right]

Comment: Use the optional argument: `\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=left}`. `right` is the default value. See section 19.3 of the `beamer` manual.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a look at the [`beamer` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf), you will find the following explanation in section 19.3:

> `\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=⟨location⟩}`
>
> When this option is given, a two screen version of your talk is created, see Section 22 for further details. The second screen, which is displayed on the right by default, shows your notes. By specifying a different *⟨location⟩*, you can also place the second screen on the `left`, `bottom`, or `top`.

So you should use

```
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=left}
```

to specify the position according to your needs.